# How do I create a custom file in swift?

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager, file-type

For my mac application (in swift), I currently save data by writing & reading .txt files. To make the files look more professional, how can I write a file with:

- a custom extension
- a custom preview image
- data structured like a plist (maybe xml?)

EDIT: This is what I am currently using (not that it is useful):

```
let root = XMLElement(name: "root")
let xml = XMLDocument(rootElement: root)
root.addChild(XMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "125"))
root.addChild(XMLElement(name: "key", stringValue: "kF15304g3DlJkR"))

let fileName = "File"

let directory = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

if var fileURL = directory?.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("xml") {

    do {
    try xml.xmlString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    do {
        var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
        resourceValues.hasHiddenExtension = true
        //resourceValues.thumbnail is get-only!?!? :( how do I set it?
        try fileURL.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```